# Auth errors when starting a widget for bigcommerce

Tags: widget, bigcommerce

Need help installing widget builder. I cloned our repo for widgets, then I did npm i > npm run install-cli > widget init (I am sure that the auths are correct). Then after widget-builder create , I did widget-builder start  and this where I got these errors. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I am sure that the auths are correct and the .env file is located in the root folder.

```
[2023-06-04T22:54:31.157Z] authId is invalid.
[2023-06-04T22:54:31.159Z] apiPath is invalid.
[2023-06-04T22:54:31.159Z] authToken is invalid.
```